# Liferay internal dependencies

Tags: maven, liferay, liferay-6

Is there any wiki page or something, where I can find the Liferay internal dependencies with version?

For example: i want to use log4j logging, or commons-fileupload

I have Maven project, i declare a new dependency, with a `provided` scope. But what version should I use?

(We are working with an EE licenced portal instance, so digging into github may not be the best)

Comment: what you couldn't let the maven do the trick for you? liferay have bunch of artifacts, which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download a tomcat bundle, watch out for the file `license/versions.html`. This contains all third party libraries, their license and their version.

Note that some libraries might be patched to fix a bug, so they might not be official releases.

Comment: Brute force solution I use is to make a maven sub-module that'll retrieve your target bundle zip (preferably from nexus), unzip all and install needed jar's back to your shared nexus repo with a Liferay Portal version of your choice. In this way you'll be always sure to use the correct lib. Than you can include those libs back in other modules as provided and declare them to be installed by Liferay's autodeployer in plugin descriptor. I can share this config if you like the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way recommended by Liferay STAFF. Unfortunately this will not avoid you from visiting github.

- **6.1.0-ga1**: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.0-ga1/lib/versions.xml
- **6.2.x**: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/lib/versions.xml

As you can see, for example spring-core version for these liferay versions:

6.1.0-ga1 - **3.0.6**

```
<library>
   <file-name>portal/spring-core.jar</file-name>
   <version>3.0.6</version>
   <project-name>Spring</project-name>
   <project-url>http://www.springframework.org</project-url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
      <license-name>Apache License 2.0</license-name>
   </license>
   </licenses>
</library>
```

6.2.x - **3.0.7**

```
<library>
   <file-name>lib/portal/spring-core.jar</file-name>
   <version>3.0.7</version>
   <project-name>Spring</project-name>
   <project-url>http://www.springframework.org</project-url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <license-name>Apache License 2.0</license-name>
         <license-url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</license-url>
      </license>
   </licenses>
</library>
```

I don't think there is actually easier way than just browsing this version.xml or .html file. From other hand, from my experience this is easiest way, not only in this scenario, since documentation of Liferay can be very poor in some parts.